# In C++ using MSVC, how to enumerate all exceptions which could be thrown by a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-c++, static-analysis

Is there a way in Visual Studio to enumerate all directly or transitively thrown exceptions for a given C++ function or method other than studying code or documentation?

Comment: I don't believe so, and you can't even know by studying the code - e.g. some exceptions are thrown due to hardware conditions, like attempted division by zero, stack overflow, or out-of-memory.

Comment: Division by zero and stack overflow are not C++ exceptions. Out of memory (`std::bad_alloc`) is a C++ exception though. In any case, this sounds like an XY problem. To the OP: Why do you need to know this list?

Comment: This question suffers from [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Pelase explain why do you need this kind of feature? Note also that since C++11 [dynamic exception specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) been deprecated and was removed in C++17.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i need to know which exceptions are thrown so i can decide which exceptions i could handle (not all of them). I wouldn't handle bad_alloc but many control flow exceptions, f.e. when some high level method uses a low level method which changes the directory and this isn't possible a ui handler can detect this state and report the error to the user without crashing the application.

Comment: Why "other than documentation" ? Documentation is the place to find this information. For example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string#Exceptions. For libraries other than the standard lib I would always add a `...` catch too to be sure.

Comment: @MarekR the code and libraries i'm working with are not documented when it comes to exceptions they explicitly throw. Some of them can and should be handled tho. I don't understand why this is a XY problem. Can you please elaborate? Should i not handle any exceptions?

Comment: anyhow its not sufficient to enumerate all types of exceptions a function may throw. You do need to read documentation to know why they throw and how to recover, otherwise there is no point in catching the exception in the first place

Comment: The answer is **no**.  You can read the code.  You can read the documentation.  But that may omit dependent code that may throw exceptions.  Short of being *omniscient* or *psychic*, there's not much hope for complete and comprehensive accuracy to enumerate all possible exceptions unless the code is small enough, self-contained, and complete.

Comment: If a function calls some other function, that some other function can throw any exception that will propagate through the function call. Your suffering C++ compiler is not capable of opening that other function, in some other library that the compiler did not even compile, and decompile that code in order to figure out which exceptions it could possibly throw. This is logically impossible.

Comment: its a XY-Problem because what you literally ask for is not possible. However, what you literally ask for (automagically enumerate all exceptions thrown by some arbitrary function) isnt something one usually needs. If you explain why you think you need it perhaps we can help you to find a different solution (which is not about enumerating all). I still wonder what you would do with that information. Say you know a function `foo` potentially throws an excpetion of type `bar`. If thats all you know, there is little you can do about it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai if i know foo only throws bar and possibly list all methods (it has the source code from) to show me where bar is thrown i could save a lot of time. Right now, i have to walk the source code tree manually.

Comment: save time for what? What will you do with the knowledge that `foo` potentially throws a `bar` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai i handle it like i'd handle exceptions https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol might throw once i understand if bar needs to be handled by looking at the source code.

Comment: One important info you added was that you're dealing with smelly and/or legacy code. What I would do is to assume it throws `std::exception`, which is a sane default for any (good and bad) code. Now, if some lib throws its own exception types, add handler as becomes apparent from actual use cases. Proactively and without an actual need trying to cover every possible exception type is a futile approach in my experience.

Comment: What exceptions can `void f(void callback()) { callback(); }` throw? Unless you are happy with "`noexcept(expr)` ? `expr` cannot throw exceptions : `expr` could throw any exception of any type", I don't think you can get a better answer. A static analyzer might be able to give you some hints.